# Problem with script to extract strings from database field

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

what am I doing wrong?

I am generating a button for each price option for each product number which may be up to 12 price options from an SQL database. That works fine. For each button created, I am generating each item variables for div1price, div2 price etc, div1minorder, div2minorder etc, div1pricequantity, div2 price quantity etc. So when a price option button is pressed, it displays the price, minimum order and minimum quantity for that particular size. All works apart from it only works when numbers are in the data - strings throw errors which defeats the object. I know I am doing something wrong fundamentally but can’t work out what. Think it must be to do with the eval! Please be gentle - very amateur coder. Thank you

| Price Option | Price | Price Quantity | Min Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Small | £3 | Each | 1 |
| Medium | £5 | Case of 2 | 2 |
| Large | £7 | 3 | 1 |
| Extra Large | £9 | Each | 2 |

```js
/* needs proper JavaScript formatting perhaps for the <% %> things
$('#divx').attr('id', 'div' + butno);
price = <% =(price.Fields.Item("itemprice").Value)%>;
minorder = <% =(price.Fields.Item("minquantity").Value)%>;
pricequantity = <% =(price.Fields.Item("pricequantity").Value)%>;
a = ('div' + butno + 'price');
a2 = ('div' + butno + 'minorder');
a3 = ('div' + butno + 'pricequantity');
eval('var ' + a + '= ' + price + ';');
eval('var ' + a2 + '= ' + minorder + ';');
eval('var ' + a3 + '= ' + pricequantity + ';');
butno = butno + 1;
*/

$("#div1").click(function() {
  $("#bigprice").text('£' + div1price);
  $("#minorder").text('Minimum Order Quantity: ' + div1minorder);
  $("#pricequantity").text('Price Quantity: ' + div1pricequantity);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>HTML here please to reproduce this</div>
```

```
<script>
    $('#divx').attr('id', 'div' + butno);
    price = <% =(price.Fields.Item("itemprice").Value)%>;
    minorder = <% =(price.Fields.Item("minquantity").Value)%>;
    pricequantity = <% =(price.Fields.Item("pricequantity").Value)%>;
    a = ('div' + butno + 'price');
    a2 = ('div' + butno + 'minorder');
    a3 = ('div' + butno + 'pricequantity');
    eval ('var ' + a + '= ' + price + ';');
    eval ('var ' + a2 + '= ' + minorder + ';');
    eval ('var ' + a3 + '= ' + pricequantity + ';');
    butno = butno+1;
   </script>
```

I have tried the above and it works fine when all numbers are involved. The logic indicates I am not extracting the string.

Sorry, didn't include the click code for buttons. Here is the code for first of 12 possible buttons.

```
    <script>
    $("#div1").click(function(){
    $("#bigprice").text('£' + div1price);
    $("#minorder").text('Minimum Order Quantity: ' + div1minorder);
    $("#pricequantity").text('Price Quantity: ' + div1pricequantity);
    });
</script>
```

For clarity the a, a2 and a3 sections of code generate the variable names, the eval parts assign values from the database to each variable. May not be elegant but seems to work apart from the string values

Comment: Can you also add the exact error that you are getting and on which line?

Comment: I am not getting an error in the code, as such. When I click say the first button and change the price quantity to 111 and the min quantity to 11 it correctly tells me the price is £3, the price quantity is 111 and the min quantity is 11 but when I replace with text as above, the button does not change anything. Obviously, the variables are not working when non-numeric!

Comment: Why don't you work with objects/associative arrays instead of bunch of variables? It would be much easier to debug and work with. Right now what I see: 1. Code is executed once on page load, not when button is clicked; 2. There is no `divXprice`, only `price` (same with other fields). 3. You never use these variables anywhere; 4. Type-cast your values to int/float to bypass type errors

Comment: Basically the system loops as many times as a product price is valid, creates the buttons, creates a variable for each aspect of the price and assigns variables from the appropriate line of the database. Using an array would in my opinion be extra work for no added value. All I need is for each variable to work as a string component to print the text value on the web page. As I said, it works for numbers but not text. Am I using the wrong operator in my eval statemen ie '+'

Comment: If you want to just get text in your final variable then do something like this 
 eval ('var ' + a + '=  \"' + price + '\";');   Adding escaped quotes to string before and after your variable. It should work with both number and strings

Comment: Generally if you have `eval (` in JavaScript you are probably doing something wrong..

Perhaps put a working snippet in with the HTML, JavaScript and whatever library versions you have for jQuery etc. needed to reproduce this.

Comment: I created a snippet of PART of this code, perhaps you can leverage that to add some HTML and/or other markup to get a working example of what you have.  Bottom line I think your approach can be altered to do this "better" differently

Comment: I think the issue is solved thanks to the answer provided by SteelFeather. Code worked perfectly in addition to single quote tweak around the code to get each database field. Also thanks to Mark Schultheiss who is correct - I need to make the code more efficient. Thank you all

Comment: @Frogger - can you mark the answer if it worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in the comment just enclose your price/minorder variables in escaped double/single quotes. Some sample code

```
let x = 'test';
let y = 10;

let a1 = 'div' + 1;
let a2 = 'div' + 2;

eval('var ' + a1 + '= \"' + x + '\";');
eval('var ' + a2 + '= \"' + y + '\";');
console.log(div1);
console.log(div2);
```